# How do I output a specific item in a list when inputted a number that corresponds to that item? [Indexing?]

Tags: list, indexing, split

Number,IceCream
1,Chocolate
2,Vanilla
3,Mixed

Say if I

Number = input("Flavor?:")

I know that I need to index [0] because the numbers are on the first column. I also know that I will need to use .split(",") to remove the commas and to create a list.

Some assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: You should edit this question to include a language tag. It is unclear in what programming language you want a solution, or in what language those code examples are in.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing whether you plan to include integers in the list with the strings or not

**Method 1**: including integers with strings(flavor), create a list of tuples

```py
icecream=[(1,'choc'),(2,'mix'),(3,'blueberry')] 
print(icecream[0][1]) 
print(icecream[2][1])
```

**Note:** tuples are immutable

**Method 2**: I believe the best way to do this would be to use a dictionary instead of list. As dictionary has `(Key, value)` pairs, you could assign key(integer) to values(flavor), which then would make it easy accessing items just by keys(integers in your case) ex.

```py
Ice_cream_flavors={1:"chocolate", 2:"vanilla", 3:"mixed"} #dictionary
```

to access values, you could use methods available in dictionary use `get()`, `items()`

**Note:** `items()` returns a tuple for each key,value pair.

ex.

```py
Ice_cream_flavors={1:"chocolate", 2:"vanilla", 3:"mixed"}    
new=Ice_cream_flavors.items()    
for k,v in new:     
    if input==k:            
        print(v)
```

Comment: You can index a dictionary by a key, for example: `Ice_cream_flavors[1]` will return `"chocolate"`. It's the same as doing `get`

Comment: @JorgeMorgado thank you for the correction, i didn't know at the time of posting it was fairly new.